# What is the most efficient way to periodically download all new 10-K filings from SEC's EDGAR?

Tags: sec, edgar

I found [this website](http://www.wrds.us/index.php/tutorial/view/26) which uses a perl script to download all the filings. It states: "There are 200K+ 10-K (and equivalent) filings, which will take considerable harddisk space and time to download. The SEC prefers that bulk-download is done during 'quiet time', i.e., outside the regular trading hours."

Is there a better way than deluging the SEC's servers with requests to get this information?

Answer (score 1):

#### 10-K - Historical Fundamentals Only

If you are just interested in the fundamentals (income statement, balance sheet, cash flow statement) of 10-Ks, then you can use the provider [eodhistoricaldata.com](https://eodhistoricaldata.com/knowledgebase/stock-etfs-fundamental-data-feeds/). I'm a paying customer, and use their APIs on a daily basis. Price is $10/month for accessing fundamentals of 37K stocks (world wide), 6K ETFs, and 20K mutual funds.

You can use the method `getFundamentals(ticker)` provided by the library `eodhistoricaldata-api` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/eodhistoricaldata-api), or access their RESTful API directly.

You can access the API programmatically, without requiring you to download all reports at once.

The API returns JSON data, for example:

```
"Highlights": {
    "MarketCapitalization": 54915055616,
    "MarketCapitalizationMln": "54915.0556",
    "EBITDA": 616286976,
    "PERatio": null,
    "PEGRatio": "-1.5700",
    "WallStreetTargetPrice": "321.8900",
    "BookValue": "26.2790",
    "DividendShare": null,
    "DividendYield": null,
    "EarningsShare": "-4.8500",
    "EPSEstimateCurrentYear": "-6.5600",
    "EPSEstimateNextYear": "-2.0000",
    "EPSEstimateNextQuarter": "-1.6700",
    "MostRecentQuarter": "2018-09-30",
    "ProfitMargin": "-0.1022",
    "OperatingMarginTTM": "-0.0710",
    "ReturnOnAssetsTTM": "-0.0271",
    "ReturnOnEquityTTM": "-0.3397",
    "RevenueTTM": "17523644416.00",
    "RevenuePerShareTTM": "103.3240",
    "QuarterlyRevenueGrowthYOY": "1.2860",
    "GrossProfitTTM": "2222487000.00",
    "DilutedEpsTTM": "-10.5600",
    "QuarterlyEarningsGrowthYOY": null
},
// ...
"Income_Statement": {
        "currency_symbol": "USD",
        "quarterly": {
            "2018-09-30": {
                "date": "2018-09-30",
                "filing_date": "2018-11-02",
                "researchDevelopment": "350848000.00",
                "effectOfAccountingCharges": null,
                "incomeBeforeTax": "271320000.00",
                "minorityInterest": "1344731000.00",
                "netIncome": "311516000.00",
                "sellingGeneralAdministrative": "729876000.00",
                "grossProfit": "1523665000.00",
                "ebit": "442941000.00",
                "operatingIncome": "442941000.00",
                "otherOperatingExpenses": null,
                "interestExpense": "-169858000.00",
                "extraordinaryItems": null,
                "nonRecurring": null,
                "otherItems": null,
                "incomeTaxExpense": "16647000.00",
                "totalRevenue": "6824413000.00",
                "totalOperatingExpenses": "6381472000.00",
                "costOfRevenue": "5300748000.00",
                "totalOtherIncomeExpenseNet": "-171621000.00",
                "discontinuedOperations": null,
                "netIncomeFromContinuingOps": "254673000.00",
                "netIncomeApplicableToCommonShares": "311516000.00"
            },
            // ...
"Balance_Sheet": {
        "currency_symbol": "USD",
        "quarterly": {
            "2018-09-30": {
                "date": "2018-09-30",
                "filing_date": "2018-11-02",
                "intangibleAssets": "291476000.00",
                "totalLiab": "23409144000.00",
                "totalStockholderEquity": "4508838000.00",
                "deferredLongTermLiab": "0.00",
                "otherCurrentLiab": "2266778000.00",
                "totalAssets": "29262713000.00",
                "commonStock": "171000.00",
                "otherCurrentAssets": "158627000.00",
                "retainedEarnings": "-5457315000.00",
                "otherLiab": "2285172000.00",
                "goodWill": "65226000.00",
                "otherAssets": "1233979000.00",
                "cash": "2967504000.00",
                "totalCurrentLiabilities": "9775324000.00",
                "shortLongTermDebt": "2106538000.00",
                "otherStockholderEquity": "8271000.00",
                "propertyPlantEquipment": "19733969000.00",
                "totalCurrentAssets": "7920491000.00",
                "longTermInvestments": "17572000.00",
                "netTangibleAssets": "4152136000.00",
                "shortTermInvestments": "0.00",
                "netReceivables": "1155001000.00",
                "longTermDebt": "9726589000.00",
                "inventory": "3314127000.00",
                "accountsPayable": "3596984000.00",
                "totalPermanentEquity": "0.00",
                "noncontrollingInterestInConsolidatedEntity": "0.00",
                "temporaryEquityRedeemableNoncontrollingInterests": "0.00",
                "accumulatedOtherComprehensiveIncome": "0.00",
                "additionalPaidInCapital": "0.00",
                "commonStockTotalEquity": "0.00",
                "preferredStockTotalEquity": "0.00",
                "retainedEarningsTotalEquity": "0.00",
                "treasuryStock": "0.00"
            },
            // ...
"Cash_Flow": {
        "currency_symbol": "USD",
        "quarterly": {
            "2018-09-30": {
                "date": "2018-09-30",
                "filing_date": "2018-11-02",
                "investments": null,
                "changeToLiabilities": "895197000.00",
                "totalCashflowsFromInvestingActivities": "-560965000.00",
                "netBorrowings": "-221931000.00",
                "totalCashFromFinancingActivities": "-84218000.00",
                "changeToOperatingActivities": "98770000.00",
                "netIncome": "311516000.00",
                "changeInCash": "739728000.00",
                "totalCashFromOperatingActivities": "1391281000.00",
                "depreciation": "502825000.00",
                "otherCashflowsFromInvestingActivities": "128600000.00",
                "dividendsPaid": "0.00",
                "changeToInventory": "-55055000.00",
                "changeToAccountReceivables": "-587594000.00",
                "salePurchaseOfStock": "0.00",
                "otherCashflowsFromFinancingActivities": "42839000.00",
                "changeToNetincome": "179168000.00",
                "capitalExpenditures": "-559765000.00"
            },
```

#### 10-K - Real-Time

I suggest `sec-api` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sec-api) if you need real-time access to 10-K filings. It provides a websocket (real-time) channel. As soon as a new filing is published on sec.gov EDGAR, the library fires an event, and returns information about the new filing as follows (JSON format):

```
{  
  companyName:            'WALT DISNEY CO/ (0001001039) (Issuer)',  
  cik:                    '0001001039',
  type:                   '10-K',  
  description:            'FORM 10-K',  
  linkToFilingDetails:    'https://www.sec.gov/...',  
  linkToHtmlAnnouncement: 'https://www.sec.gov/...',  
  linkToXbrl:             'https://www.sec.gov/...',  
  announcedAt:            '2018-12-21T20:02:07-05:00'
}
```

The library works with server-side (eg Node.js) and client-side (eg React, React Native, Angular, Vue) JavaScript.

Simple Node.js implementation:

```
const api = require('sec-api')(); 
api.on('filing', filing => console.log(filing));
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a data mining package for EDGAR in python. It accepts lists of tickers as an input so you don't need to download every 10-k for every company. Just the ones you want. Hope it helps!

https://github.com/Jordan-M-Young/pyQuarry

Comment: [Data mining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mining) doesn't mean downloading data.